# Graph Explorer Query for OrderBy on SharePoint List Item ID not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Graph Explorer Query for OrderBy on SharePoint List Item ID not working Any Pointers would really help

/sites/chinnainfotech.sharepoint.com,siteid,webid/lists/QuickLinks/items?$filter(Title eq 'xyg')&$expand=fields&$Top=3&$orderby=id desc

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reaching out. To the best of my knowledge, `orderBy` is not currently supported when listing items in a Sharepoint list. As a workaround, you could list

Would you consider [filing a feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) on the M365 Developer Platform so we can look into this?

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.